# ASP.NET MVC and CKEditor - no validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor, it works fine but it turns out that there is a problem with validation. I am using this trick:

```
$('input[type=submit]').bind('click', function () {
    var ckContent = CKEDITOR.instances.Content.getData(); 
    $("#Content").val(ckContent);
});
```

To make validation work, but it doesn't help at all. I mean, when I send a form, it binds value to a textarea, but jquery doesn't want to validate this. When I turn off CKEditor completely, validation works fine on pure textarea. So what is wrong? How can I make CKEditor work with ASP.NET's validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm thinking the input select is happening too late to be validated. So I think you need to update the text box after you blur the CKEditor.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('content');
editor.on('blur', function (e) {
    $("#Content").val(this.getData());
});
```

EDIT: I'm assuming you're trying to get a required field validator to fail/pass. I forgot CKEditor will place `<p>` tags even if there is no content (by default). On your submit button click, try forcing an update:

```
$('input[type=submit]').bind('click', function () {
    CKEDITOR.instances.Content.updateElement();
});
```

SECOND EDIT: By default, jQuery validation does not validate hidden fields. To override that feature with MVC's unobstructive javascript add `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: '' });` right after the includes for the validation. This will allow all fields to be validated on the page.

Comment: Check the updated answer, I think that will work for you if you're attempting to validate for a required field.

Comment: Still nothing. :/ I checked on firebug, your code is being hit when I click submit, but then nothing happens, form is passed.

Comment: I was using an old version of everything. You are completely correct. Apparently at some recent point, probably with the updates to jQuery 1.9, all hidden elements are not validated. So, right after the include of the validation javascript files add `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: '' });`, which sets the validation defaults to ignore nothing instead of `:hidden`.

Comment: Wow. That did the trick. Thank you very much, i was depressed by that validation issue. :-D

Comment: I edited the answer with the hidden element information so it may help someone else from beating their head into a wall!